# How to build efficient react component for infinitely nested structure?

Tags: reactjs, nested, components, redux, immutable.js

I am building a react component of filter builder (Redux), the filter is an object that can be infinitely nested:

```
{
  "logic": "AND",
  "filters": [
    {
      "field": "name",
      "operator": "EQ",
      "value": "tom"
    },
    {
      "field": "clientVersion",
      "operator": "EQ",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "logic": "OR",
      "filters": [
        {
          "field": "documentCount",
          "operator": "EQ",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "logic": "AND",
          "filters": [
            {
              "field": "error",
              "operator": "NEQ",
              "value": "falses"
            }
          ]
        }        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My solution 1 is using immutable.js and passing down a 'path' prop. Any change in the nested component will dispatch an action and in reducer immutable.js will transform the state based on the path.
The issue is since 'path' is generated during render, shallow equal will always return false. All components will be re-rendered.
[code](https://github.com/queryxl/react-infinitely-nested-filter/tree/master)

Solution 2 is passing down composed action functions. The issue is the same, since on top level, mapDispatchToProps will always generate new functions.
[code](https://github.com/queryxl/react-infinitely-nested-filter/tree/solution2)

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: why can't you pass the full object as a prop? ie the top level component will have the big object you posted, it has three children, the last of which has a prop `{ logic: "OR", filters: ...}`?